# I want to isolate multiple columns in a dataframe from a vector source and convert their data type from character to numeric using R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe

```
col1|col2|col3|cola|colb|colc|cold
 "1"   "1"  "1"    x    x    x    x
```

Then I have a vector

```
 colnum<-c("col1","col2","col3")
```

I use this script to convert the specific columns in the dataframe from the vector as a source from charcacter into numeric

```
df[colnum] <- sapply(df[column],as.numeric)
```

When I first tried it it worked, but after using it again it gave me this message

```
Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) :
```

'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `lapply` instead of `sapply` as this can convert to `matrix` while `lapply` always returns a `list` and a `data.frame` is a `list` as well (with list elements i.e. columns of equal `length`)

```
df[colnum] <- lapply(df[colnum],as.numeric)
```

---

In the OP's code, there is a typo as well.  Instead of `colnum`, it is written as `column`

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, it seems that some columns are `list` as well.  In that case, we loop over those columns with `lapply`, `unlist` the `list` and convert to `numeric`

```
df[colnum] <- lapply(df[colnum], function(x) as.numeric(unlist(x)))
```

Comment: I got this message. Error in lapply(df[column], as.numeric) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: @user35131 that implies some of the columns are infact `list`.  YOu can change it to vector with `unlist` i..e `lapply(df[colnum], function(x) as.numeric(unlist(x)))`

Comment: So the columns are supposed to have only numbers. When you mean list what do you mean?

Comment: @user35131 I meant `df <- data.frame(col1 = I(list(1)), col2 = I(list(2)))`